# custom junction table in nest js with typeorm

Tags: nestjs, nest

I have a project that has made with nest, PostgreSQL and Typeorm. I have 2 tables users and roles and as you know they have many-to-many relation. junction table between them make automatically. but I avoided this way and I made a junction table named `user_role` and after I run command for migration I see I have 2 junction table, user_role that it's mine made but other table user_role_roles that is original made too. I want to make just `user_role`. How can resolve the problem?

```
import { Role } from '../../roles/model/role.schema';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserRole } from '../../user_role/model/user_role.schema';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  family: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  username: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: 1 })
  status: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created!: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated!: Date;

  // Add this column to your entity!
  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt?: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => UserRole, (role) => role.user)
  roles: UserRole[];
}
```

roles

```
import { UserRole } from '../../user_role/model/user_role.schema';
import { User } from '../../users/model/user.schema';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false, type: 'smallint', default: 1 })
  status: number;

  @OneToMany(() => UserRole, (user) => user.role)
  users: UserRole[];
}
```

user_role

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../../users/model/user.schema';
import { Role } from '../../roles/model/role.schema';

@Entity({name:"user_role"})
export class UserRole {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.roles)
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.users)
  role: Role;
}
```

and the code below is for migration as you can see I have 2 junction table

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class NewMigration1707723252426 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'NewMigration1707723252426'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "role" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "name" character varying, CONSTRAINT "PK_b36bcfe02fc8de3c57a8b2391c2" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "user" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "name" character varying, "family" character varying, "username" character varying NOT NULL, "password" character varying NOT NULL, "status" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', CONSTRAINT "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "user_role" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "userId" integer, "roleId" integer, CONSTRAINT "PK_fb2e442d14add3cefbdf33c4561" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "user_roles_role" ("userId" integer NOT NULL, "roleId" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_b47cd6c84ee205ac5a713718292" PRIMARY KEY ("userId", "roleId"))`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX "IDX_5f9286e6c25594c6b88c108db7" ON "user_roles_role" ("userId") `);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX "IDX_4be2f7adf862634f5f803d246b" ON "user_roles_role" ("roleId") `);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "role" ADD "status" smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" ADD "created" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" ADD "updated" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" ADD "deletedAt" TIMESTAMP`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_role" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_ab40a6f0cd7d3ebfcce082131fd" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "user"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_role" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_dba55ed826ef26b5b22bd39409b" FOREIGN KEY ("roleId") REFERENCES "role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_roles_role" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_5f9286e6c25594c6b88c108db77" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "user"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_roles_role" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_4be2f7adf862634f5f803d246b8" FOREIGN KEY ("roleId") REFERENCES "role"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_roles_role" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_4be2f7adf862634f5f803d246b8"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_roles_role" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_5f9286e6c25594c6b88c108db77"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_role" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_dba55ed826ef26b5b22bd39409b"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user_role" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_ab40a6f0cd7d3ebfcce082131fd"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" DROP COLUMN "deletedAt"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" DROP COLUMN "updated"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" DROP COLUMN "created"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "role" DROP COLUMN "status"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX "public"."IDX_4be2f7adf862634f5f803d246b"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX "public"."IDX_5f9286e6c25594c6b88c108db7"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "user_roles_role"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "user_role"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "user"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "role"`);
    }

}
```

how to resole this?